# Flutter Toggle Button won't Toggle Using Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have tried moving the flutter toggle from setState to bloc. I cannot get the toggle buttons to toggle.
The BlocEvent:

```
abstract class ToggleSizeEvent extends Equatable {
  const ToggleSizeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SelectSize extends ToggleSizeEvent {
  const SelectSize({
    required this.idSelected,
  });
  final int idSelected;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [idSelected];
}
```

The State:

```
enum ToggleSizeStatus { initial, success, error, loading, selected }

extension ToggleSizeStatusX on ToggleSizeStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == ToggleSizeStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == ToggleSizeStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == ToggleSizeStatus.error;
  bool get isLoading => this == ToggleSizeStatus.loading;
  bool get isSelected => this == ToggleSizeStatus.selected;
}

class ToggleSizeState extends Equatable {
  ToggleSizeState(
      {String size = '',
      // this.product,
      this.status = ToggleSizeStatus.initial,
      List<bool>? sizeSelection,
      int idSelected = 0,
      this.index = 0})
      // : sizeSelection = List.generate(product.size!.length, (index) => false),
      : idSelected = idSelected,
        size = size;

  final List<bool> sizeSelection = [false, false, false, false];

  // final ProductModel product;
  final ToggleSizeStatus status;
  final int idSelected;
  final String size;
  final int index;
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, sizeSelection, idSelected, size];

  ToggleSizeState copyWith({
    List<bool>? sizeSelection,
    ToggleSizeStatus? status,
    int? idSelected,
    String? size,
    int? index,
  }) {
    return ToggleSizeState(
        // product: product,
        sizeSelection: sizeSelection ?? this.sizeSelection,
        status: status ?? this.status,
        idSelected: idSelected ?? this.idSelected,
        size: size ?? this.size,
        index: index ?? this.index);
  }
}
```

The bloc:

```
part 'toggle_size_event.dart';
part 'toggle_size_state.dart';

class ToggleSizeBloc extends Bloc<ToggleSizeEvent, ToggleSizeState> {
  final ProductModel product;
  ToggleSizeBloc({required this.product})
      : super(ToggleSizeState(product: product)) {
    on<SelectSize>(_mapSelectSizeEventToState);
  }

  int newIndex = 0;

  void _mapSelectSizeEventToState(
      SelectSize event, Emitter<ToggleSizeState> emit) async {
    for (int index = 0; index < state.sizeSelection.length; index++) {
      if (index == newIndex) {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = !state.sizeSelection[index];
      } else {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = false;
      }
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(
        status: ToggleSizeStatus.selected,
        idSelected: event.idSelected,
        sizeSelection: state.sizeSelection));
  }
}
```

For the UI:

```
class ProductSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel product;

  const ProductSize({super.key, required this.product});

  @override
  State<ProductSize> createState() => _ProductSizeState();
}

class _ProductSizeState extends State<ProductSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text('Please select size'),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => ToggleSizeBloc(product: widget.product),
            child: BlocBuilder<ToggleSizeBloc, ToggleSizeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                debugPrint('ToggleSize Page ${state.sizeSelection}');
                return ToggleButtons(
                  selectedColor: Colors.white,
                  color: pureBlack,
                  fillColor: thistle,
                  splashColor: lilac,
                  highlightColor: lilac,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  renderBorder: true,
                  borderColor: lilac,
                  borderWidth: 1.5,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  selectedBorderColor: lilac,
                  isSelected: state.sizeSelection,
                  onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                    context.read<ToggleSizeBloc>().add(SelectSize(
                          idSelected: widget.product.id!,
                        ));
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (var item in widget.product.size!)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                        child: Text(item, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please i have been on this for a while. Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get the toggle button to toggle on selection. Am i doing the for loop in a wrong way?

```
class ProductModel {
  const ProductModel({
    this.name,
    this.size,
    this.imgsUrl,
    this.id,
    this.description,
    this.owner,
    this.price,
  });

  final String? name;
  final String? description;
  final String? price;

  final int? id;
  final String? owner;
  final List<String>? imgsUrl;
  final List<String>? size;

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModel(
        name: json["name"],
        price: json["price"],
        imgsUrl: List<String>.from(json["imgs_url"].map((x) => x)),
        size: List<String>.from(json["size"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["id"],
        description: json["description"],
        owner: json["owner"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "imgs_url": List<dynamic>.from(imgsUrl!.map((x) => x)),
        "size": List<dynamic>.from(size!.map((x) => x)),
        "id": id,
        "description": description,
        "owner": owner,
        "price": price,
      };

  static const empty = ProductModel(
    description: '',
    price: '',
    id: 0,
    imgsUrl: [],
    owner: '',
    name: '',
    size: [],
  );
}
```

For the sample data to reproduce the issu:

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Roma",
        "owner": "pythonGO",
        "price": "450485.99",
        "description": "Mixed Colored",
        "imgs_url": [
            "http://1111.com/product-images/yadrafektxqvrckoymjoqktdhwxpjnulqqymattavpvqdfzsnpsdzcxdbhmurxnfHeels.png"
        ],
        "imgs_name": [
            "product-images/yadrafektxqvrckoymjoqktdhwxpjnulqqymattavpvqdfzsnpsdzcxdbhmurxnfHeels.png"
        ],
        "size": [
            "45",
            "46",
            "47",
            "48"
        ],
        "is_promoted": {
            "Bool": false,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "is_trending": {
            "Bool": false,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "is_mens": {
            "Bool": false,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "is_womens": {
            "Bool": false,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "is_kids": {
            "Bool": false,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "created_at": "2022-10-26T08:27:22.600809Z",
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you include `ProductModel`

Comment: Hello @Yeasin. I just added the product model.

Comment: can you include sample data that will reproduce the issue,

Comment: I just did that. Thanks

Comment: @pythonGo, I think, your newIndex implementation is wrong, as it is not being updated anywhere, always comparing with 0, that's why toggling is not working. Secondly, I am also not sure how you are using a single variable(newIndex) to handle the list of buttons toggle.

Comment: @KamlendraPandey although I chose a drop-down option already, I would love to learn how to implement it. Please can you solve it? I am passing **List<bool>** to the List.Generate function as the variable. Without bloc, the toggle works. But with bloc, the toggle won’t work as expected.